# Extract Table(s) having name in numbers

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-administration

I am using Oracle developer , my DB have 150+ tables having different namings 
i Want to extract all tables having names like

tbl_1234
tbl_22
tbl_45
tbl_719

All tables whose naming convention is like " table name , underscore , number "

Pleaseee help me on this

Answer (score 2):

try following query:

```
select table_name from user_tables where regexp_like (table_name, '_[0-9]+$');
```

and you can use, of course, the `all_tables` or `dba_tables` view, if you have approriate rights